# macOS DDEV drush command Permission denied (Experimental docker settings)

Tags: drupal, drush, ddev

When I updated ddev version 1.19.0 then drush command doesn't work.

```
$ ddev drush
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/mnt/ddev_config/.global_commands/web/drush": permission denied: unknown
Failed to run drush : exit status 126
```

So, I have to use command **ddev exec drush** instead of **ddev drush**

Who does have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say much about your environment, but I imagine you're on macOS and you installed Docker Desktop 4.6.0+ and you enabled the experimental virtualization and VirtioFS features. Please uncheck them, they're not ready for prime time. For performance, I recommend enabling mutagen, people love it, https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/performance/#using-mutagen

[image: unchecked virtualization features]

Comment: That's correct!!! Thank you so mush