# `ddev magento` results in `permission denied: unknown`

Tags: magento2, ddev

After running `ddev start` I cannot run magento commands from outside of the container.

```
% ddev magento
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/mnt/ddev_config/.global_commands/web/magento": permission denied: unknown
Failed to run magento : exit status 126
```

the above mentioned path does exist inside the container.

`ddev exec magento` works.

`ddev composer` works.

```
name: myproject
type: magento2
docroot: pub
php_version: "7.4"
webserver_type: nginx-fpm
router_http_port: "80"
router_https_port: "443"
xdebug_enabled: false
additional_hostnames: []
additional_fqdns: []
mariadb_version: "10.3"
mysql_version: ""
use_dns_when_possible: true
composer_version: ""
web_environment: []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention your environment but I imagine you're on macOS with Docker and have enabled experimental settings. Please turn them off... they don't really work right yet. See [macOS DDEV drush command Permission denied (Experimental docker settings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71565708/macos-ddev-drush-command-permission-denied-experimental-docker-settings)