# Why can't I execute vendor/bin/drush (no execute permission on the file)

Tags: docker, drush, ddev

I have a docker and DDEV setup running on a linux/amd64 machine.

While all commands are working as expected, does `ddev drush ...` not.

This error is given:

`/mnt/ddev_config/.global_commands/web/drush: line 14: /var/www/html/vendor/bin/drush: Permission denied Failed to run drush : exit status 126` 
I have read about the [expirimental features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71565708/macos-ddev-drush-command-permission-denied-experimental-docker-settings) but am not able to disbale them.

Due to this article I created a [daemon.json](https://thenewstack.io/how-to-enable-docker-experimental-features-and-encrypt-your-login-credentials/) in `/etc/docker`

```json
{
  "experimental": false
}
```

but did didn't resolve my problem

**info:**

```yaml
// docker version
Client:
 Version:           20.10.14+dfsg1
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18
 Git commit:        a224086
 Built:             Wed Mar 30 16:07:00 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true
```

Comment: Exit code 126 probably means that /var/www/html/vendor/bin/drush is not executable. Please check inside the container and see if it is. `ls -l /var/www/html/vendor/bin/drush`. Then look on the host side. Is it executable there? `ls -l vendor/bin/drush`. If not, something probably happened to your repo files.

Comment: What is the correct permission? inside the container is 666/rw-rw-rw and 644/-rw-r--r-- on the host. 
I'm only able to run `ddev drush cr` if executable is set to `chmod 777 vendor/bin/drush`

Comment: The normal permission would be 755. It has to be executable. 777 should be fine as well. `chmod 777 vendor/bin/drush` is fine, so is `chmod +x vendor/bin/drush`

Comment: You seem to have somehow removed the executable bit from vendor/bin/drush... but if you did that via a git problem or something else, you'll likely have trouble with other things as well, so beware.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Might indeed have a git problem. thnx for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for your problem is that vendor/bin/drush has somehow gotten its executable bit removed (apparently on the host side), so when `ddev drush` tries to execute it, it fails... because it's not executable.

The error message tried to explain this: "/var/www/html/vendor/bin/drush: Permission denied Failed to run drush : exit status 126" and the exit code 126 is about executable status.

The fix is `chmod +x vendor/bin/drush`